# Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system, make

Tags: c, macos, cmake

When install make on Mac OX it shows:

> Error when bootstrapping CMake: Cannot find appropriate C compiler on
>   this system. Please specify one using environment variable CC.

However, I have Xcode on my MacBook and C/C++ are both able to run.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You need to install the command line tools too.  Use `xcode-select install`.

Comment: What package are you trying to install? How do you install it?

Answer (score 4):

I’m guessing that, like me, you were doing this using homebrew - and on MacOS 10.12 Sierra which (at the time of writing) [is tecnically not currently supported](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/364).

If you haven’t solved this yet, here’s what I did...

**TL;DR- Moral of the tale: when using homebrew with XCode provided clang compiler tooling always make sure you are up-to-date (and have installed and accepted the T&C’s for using the command line tools).**

I was trying to upgrade CMake and I got the same error during its bootstrap:

```
Error when bootstrapping CMake: Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system. Please specify one using environment variable CC
```

So I realised (as did @Jonathan Leffler) that this is probably required:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Which fixed it (I also suspect providing an alternative compiler with brew install gcc** might have worked…)

But then I got:

```
==> ./bootstrap --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.1 --no-system-libs --parallel=4 --datadir=/share/cmake --docdir=/share/doc/cmake --ma
Last 15 lines from /Users/tim/Library/Logs/Homebrew/cmake/01.bootstrap:

     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk

 Please set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 10.11 or lower.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:19 (project)
```

Then of course I have to upgrade to the latest XCode (8.1) to update the SDK. This takes ages. Groan.

Followed (on the command  line) by acceptance of licence:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

But once that was done, everything worked - i.e. `brew upgrade cmake`!

Answer (score 1):

When I typed `./bootstrap` that happened to me as well.
This worked for me:

```
env CC=gcc ./bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system, make**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```